# I just wanted to open a window doing nothing just a simple display but it immediately closes through python code

Tags: python, pygame

```py
import pygame
        
        
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

WIDTH , HEIGHT = 900 , 500
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH , HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("First Game!")

FPS = 60

def draw_window():
    WIN.fill(WHITE)
    pygame.display.update()


def main():
    run = True 
    while run :
        for event in pygame.event.get(): #error is here
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        pygame.quit()

        draw_window()

pygame.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__" : 
    main()
```

and the screen opens and immediately closes, like just in an instant, but it transitions to the "first pygame" window.

Comment: It closes because of `pygame.quit()`. Remove `pygame.quit()` from the application loop. (That one in the `while` loop)

Answer (score 0):

```
run = True 
    while run :
        for event in pygame.event.get(): #error is here
          if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
```

Instead of changing run you are creating new bool running

```
while run :
        for event in pygame.event.get(): #error is here
          if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        pygame.quit()
```

After checking the events program shuts itself because of pygame.quit() after for loop

```
while run :
        for event in pygame.event.get(): #error is here
          if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
       
        draw_window()
```

this is how it should look.